# Can anyone tell me why the share operator in RxJava2 (v2.2.4) does not operate as asserted in my unit test?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, rx-java2

Based on my understanding of the `share` operator I've written the following test:

```
@Test
fun `share operator`() {
  val expectedInvocations = 1
  val counter = AtomicInteger()
  val shared = Completable.fromCallable { counter.incrementAndGet() }
    .toObservable<Any>()
    .share()
    .ignoreElements()

  Completable.merge(listOf(shared, shared)).test()

  assertThat(counter.get()).isEqualTo(expectedInvocations)
}
```

As can be seen, I expect that if I share an observable and multiple observers subscribe simultaneously, the callable will only be invoked once. However, when I run this test it fails since the callable is invoked twice.

Comment: Your source is synchronous and ends immediately, thus share disconnects and then reconnects when the merge goes over to the second `shared` instance.

Comment: @akarnokd This was my initial suspicion and the solution requires use of `subscribeOn`. However, I don't fully comprehend why adding the `subscribeOn` operator on `shared` doesn't propagate up to `fromCallable`. It seems to apply to the result of `share()` operator. If `subscribeOn` is placed before `share()` using `TestScheduler` with `triggerActions` invoked after the merge, the outcome is as expected. I suspect that this means if, in production, I use `share`, if any of the upstream sources are synchronous, I'll observe the same behavior?

Comment: Not sure what you try to achieve here by using `share`. When the source is finite, it will complete and share disconnects, only a matter of time so if there are multiple observers, they may miss the active window. Are you trying to cache results and replay them back? sharing a single-element source makes it less likely multiple observers can get the data, and you may end up getting nothing or a reconnect. See the [refCount](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/observables/ConnectableObservable.html#refCount-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-).

Comment: I'm trying to make a multitude of network and database calls merged into an observable and would like to know when they complete. If that work is in progress I would like to share it across observers. If the operation has already completed when a new observer subscribes, it would be acceptable to do the work again.

Comment: A scheduler before share, even the testscheduler, will delay the actual subscription to the source so that merge can subscribe to both of the sources, then the (test)scheduler will facilitate the subscription to the source fromCallable.

Answer (score 1):

http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Completable.html

> merge(Iterable sources)
>
> Returns a Completable instance that subscribes to all sources at once and completes only when all source Completables complete or one of them emits an error.

**subscribes to all sources at once**
 and 
**completes only when all source Completables complete**

Therefore both completeables are actioned, making your counter 2.

---

Interesting read explaining share: https://medium.com/mindorks/how-to-use-rxjava-share-operator-26b08973771a